# Turning addresses into GPS coordinates into delivery route

Tags: google-maps, software-recommendations, route

I have a list of locations (prospects I need to meet) I have to drive to, and I'd like to use either Google Maps or Open Street View to build an optimized route.

Are there tools that can take a CSV list of locations and generate a driving route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the programmatic solution a rough plan of the workflow is as follows:

1. Grab the CSV and turn it into an array
2. Loop thru the points of the result array
3. For each pair of points calculate the driving distance between them which will also pass back an array of points that is used to plot the polyline.
4. Collect these arrays and then loop thru this array of arrays to plot all polylines.

If you need clarification, I am happy to help you! Of course you want to do the CSV parsing server side and then do the rest on the client side using javascript.

Alternatively, if you don't have that many points in your CSV, you can use the following route request of the google directions api.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false
```

Note that the waypoints of the route are separated with the pipe characters (|).
You can also modify the order of your waypoints by setting the `waypoint_order` field, like `"waypoint_order": [ 1, 0, 2, 3 ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some programmatic way adding your csv to array then for getting manual solution.

Beside this you can achieve this task with Greasemonkey. there is some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901399/430408).
you should change the code to your needs.

[image: googlemap]

and the last thing you should check out [POIConverter](http://rjdavies.users.btopenworld.com/html/poiconverter.html) to find another solution.