# Add bunch of numbered locations?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, software-recommendations

To avoid carrying books and optimize things while traveling, I like to build a Google Map with sights and cafés/restaurants. I usually print it on paper or keep a PDF in my phone so that I don't pay for a data connection.

But single Google Map is unable to take a bunch of addresses as input and doesn't offer a way to number locations, it's very time-consuming. I had to find and download numbered thumbtacks. [Here](http://wholelottalove.free.fr/prague.sights.png)'s an example of Prague I started today.

Are there add-on's to either Google Maps or OpenStreetMap that provide a better solution?

Ideally, I could just paste a list of addresses, it would add all the locations on a map, each with a number, and let me re-order the locations easily.

---

Google Maps has the option of importing date from a KML, KMZ, or GeoRSS file.

Could this be the solution?

Comment: Isn't this similar to your previous question?

Comment: I didn't ask this question before. Apparently, neither Ggoogle nor OSM support numbered locations.

Comment: I think @awesomo is referring to this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25847/turning-addresses-into-gps-coordinates-into-delivery-route

Answer (score 5):

Geographic data that describes a location can be geocoded and placed on a map very easily by using Google Fusion Tables which you can find under Google Drive.

Here is an example I made to show you how to add a list of addresses on Google Map.

**Step 1:**

Organize your address information into a excel or CSV table similar to this one below.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Open your Google Drive and create a new fusion table. Select the excel table you generated from Step 1 as your input table.

[image]

You will have a new Fusion table looks like this one below:

[image]

**Step 3:**

Click the column name "Address" and select the first option which is "Change"; then change the type of your address column to "Location" and click OK.

[image]

**Step 4:**

After that, go to file and click the option "Geocode" to map these addresses on Google map.

[image]

**Step 5:**

Click OK when the geocoding is done and you should have all of your addresses mapped. You will be able to customize the symbol and style of your results.

[image]

I believe this will give you what you want, and [here](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1012281/?hl=en) is a documentation provided by Google about how to geocode addresses.